# Call function after clicking button to add books to user's downloads using Flask, Python, SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

The point of my website is that the user can click a "download" button next to a book, after which the book title should show up on the user's user page under the "downloaded books". Here's what the download page looks like:
[image]

Here's the user page:
[image: I want the title of the downloaded books to show up]

Here's my `models.py` file:

```
class Patron_account(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    full_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    downloaded_books = db.relationship('Book')

class Book(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(150))
    authors_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    genre = db.Column(db.String(150))
    publish_year = db.Column(db.String(150))
    publisher = db.Column(db.String(150))
    page_count = db.Column(db.Integer)
    image = db.Column(db.String(150))
    patron_account_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('patron_account.id'))
```

Here's my `views.py` file:

```
@views.route('/books', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def books():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_book = Book(id=1, title='Moby-Dick, or The Whale', authors_name='Herman Melville', genre='Adventure Novel, Epic', publish_year='1851', publisher='Harper & Brothers', page_count=378, image='mobydick.jpg')
        db.session.add(new_book)
        db.session.commit()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_book = Book(id=2, title='Paradise Lost', authors_name='John Milton', genre='Epic Poetry', publish_year='1667', publisher='Samuel Simmons', page_count=512, image='paradiselost.jpg')
        db.session.add(new_book)
        db.session.commit()
    books = Book.query.all()
    return render_template("books.html", books=books)
def download_book():
```

Here's `user_page.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block title %}User-page{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h1 class=brown_text style="text-align:center">{{ current_user.full_name }}'s User Page</h1>
    <p class="brown-line">
    </p>
    <h2 class=brown_text>Downloaded books</h2>
    <li>{% for book in downloaded_book %}</li>
    <li>{{ book.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

What should I write in the `download_book()` function to make this work? Do I need to add a third table in models.py or can this be done without extra tables? Also I'm not sure if this part in the HTML file is correct: `<li>{% for book in downloaded_book %}</li>`

Comment: 1, 2: Add an association table to track user's downloaded books: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many
3: Check your templating language docs for your last question.

Comment: I still don't know how to write the function even with an association table. How do I track the user's downloaded books?

Comment: Your download book function should have a user_id and book_id. You can directly create an entity in the associative table, or with the ORM way: use session.get() to load the user and the book. Your relationship between user and book should be set up properly (many-to-many with associative table), so that you can append the book object to your user's downloaded book list. Then you call `session.commit()` to persist the change.

Your problem is you don't have a clear concept. The docs have a great tutorial, read it first!

Comment: Also, you ask too many questions in the same post, making it hard for this post to contain a meaningful answer for future reference. Organizing your questions is also important before you post.